# Using functions efficiently in Oracle queries

Tags: sql, oracle

If I have a SQL query in Oracle with a bunch of nested but repetitive functions like:

```
select trim('0' from trim(' ' from address))
from customers
where
    trim('0' from trim(' ' from address)) <> '1234 MAIN ST' and
    trim('0' from trim(' ' from address)) <> '1234 WOOD ST'
```

is there some way of caching/naming the result of `trim('0' from trim(' ' from address))` so that I'm not running it over and over again?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
With temp as (
select trim('0' from trim(' ' from address)) col1 from customers
)
Select * from temp
Where col1 <> '1234 MAIN ST' and
         col1 <> '1234 WOOD ST'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an inline view to create the column with an alias and then reference that alias in the outer query:

```
select trimmed_address
from
(
    select trim('0' from trim(' ' from address)) trimmed_address
    from customers
)
where trimmed_address not in ('1234 MAIN ST', '1234 WOOD ST');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your query this way:

```
select trim('0' from trim(' ' from address))
from customers
where
    trim('0' from trim(' ' from address)) NOT IN ( '1234 MAIN ST',
                                                   '1234 WOOD ST',
                                                   ...
                                                 )
```